# How to Render and Update a Modal to show progress of a Typescript code?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, modal-dialog

I am working on a web extension and I need to track and display the progress of execution of a particular typescript file as it has a lot of HTTP calls. The format of my typescript code is like this:

```
var content ="";
var arr=[];
this.getFileList( // parameters here )
.then((list)=>{
 list.forEach(item=>{
 arr.push(this.getFileText(item.url));
   });

await Promise.all(arr)
.then(val=>{
val.forEach(elem=>{
content.concat(elem);
     });
  });

});
```

Now I need to display the updates in a modal or something. So for that I have a separate HTML file that has the code for the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need a way to render this HTML file from the typescript file only and update it's content with the status of execution of the typescript file(for e.g. "File List Obtained","Files are being read" etc.). How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you're using JavaScript, not TypeScript. Regardless, you will need to track the state of each promise in the array of promises and calculate a percentage based on each state. For example, you can use three states: `NOT_STARTED` with value `0`, `STARTED` with value `0.5`, `COMPLETE` with value `1`. Then you can calculate the percentages, like `states.reduce((acc, state) => acc + state.value, 0) / states.length` (as 0 through 1). Then run the reducer and display the new value after a state updates.

Comment: I want to know how to display the progress. Like how to render the web page and update it's content. Calculating the progress is not what I am asking for.